Calculating array values recursively in octave/matlab
There is an array, whose nth item is calculated using the (n-1)th item. How can this be done efficiently (without a for loop)?
E.g.:
A(n) = B(n) + (A(n-1) - B(n)) * e^(-t(n))

A(n) = A(n-1) * e^(-t(n)) + B(n) * (1 - e^(-t(n)))

The example put in a loop:
t=[1:1000];
B=[1:1000].^2;
A=zeros(1,1000);
A(1)=0;
for n=[2:length(t)]
    A(n) = B(n) + (A(n-1) - B(n)) * e^(-t(n));
endfor
plot(t, A)

EDIT: I prefer an octave solution, so I removed the matlab tag. However, if there is a matlab function that does just this, I am still interested.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298705/generating-iterative-sequence-without-using-for-loop, in particular it's impossible to calculate something iterative without doing the iterations. If x(n+1) is dependent on x(n) then you must calculate x(n) first. Ensure you're using pre-allocation and create a [mcve] which can be adapted if you want something we can adapt to try and improve performance.

@CrisLuengo It works with a loop. I wanted to see if there is an alternative, or there is a clever rearrangement of the algorithm I did not realize (maybe for doing 10x or 100x the resolution).

@CrisLuengo I mean both octave/matlab since the 2 diverged, and I want to know if there is a built-in solution in any of those programs for such a problem. But right now I do use octave for this.

@Wolfie I wanted to know if there is a general solution for smth like this, not intent on improving any particular code. The example you linked is exactly the kind of solution I was thinking about. My thinking was, maybe there is a built-in I can give a lambda to, which can use the (n-1)th item. But unlike your example, not a function for a specific calculation, rather, a general one is what I want.

One tip: Don't use [] unless you're concatenating two or more arrays together. t=1:1000 is the right syntax. This is especially important in the loop, where you might be inhibiting optimizations with for n=[2:length(t)] that can be applied with for n=2:length(t). Also, e^x is better written as exp(x), which is likely more precise and/or faster.

This is difficult to vectorize, I can't immediately rewrite your expression in terms of cumsum or cumprod. But in MATLAB your code runs too fast to time. I had to add 5 zeros to the size of the arrays, now it runs in ~0.05 s. In MATLAB it just doesn't make sense to attempt to vectorize this. If it's even possible at all, it'll be very complex code that doesn't look like the expression you're evaluating, making the code so much harder to maintain. Sure, Octave is slower. If this is a bottleneck, make an Oct-file: https://docs.octave.org/v9.1.0/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html

There are some simpler recursive items that have closed form not recursive solutions. Mainly those are linear recursions.  It can quickly get messy though.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Note that in both of your example A(n) relationships above, the other items (B(n), t(n), exp(t(n)), etc) are nonrecursve and can be calculated in vectorized form outside of the recursive loop.  Then, that leave simple firwf order linear recursive with variable coefficients, which has a closed form.  This would probably make a useful utility function in octave in anyone wants to code it up.

@CrisLuengo Ok, thx for that. "Not can be done" is an acceptable answer. I have put a bunch of other stuff in the loop, but the main issue is that I run this with many different parameter sets. Right now I get a plot in a few seconds - all runs with the different params are plotted on the same figure -, but it means I cannot really add a more parameters with a more values (add a new parameter with 2 values, calculate the thing with both, the runtime is doubled). I wanted to see if there is a solution other, than moving to another language.

@NickJ This recurrence solving is something I was looking for (did not know the name for it, could not find). Unfortunately, it seems the performance suffers from the same issue as the original form. For computing a(n), Prod{f(n)} is required, but how can we use Prod{f(n-1)} in computing it without an explicit for loop in octave?

You can compute “p(n) = Prod{f(i)}, 1<=i<=n“ for all n with cumprod(f).

I conclude that eliminating such a for loop in a way that is more performant within octave/matlab is not possible right now.
Eliminating the recurrence is possible, but taking into account how it can be implemented, it does not offer performance benefits.
If performance is an issue, moving to another language is the best way.
